# AWS - Has anyone successfully used traffic mirroring to a target in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-traffic

We're setting up a traffic mirror session to mirror our incoming production data (in eu-west-1) to a proof of concept setup, which is located in another region (eu-central-1). According to this article it's possible to mirror to another region: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/mirroring/traffic-mirroring-how-it-works.html

However, I haven't found a way to actually get the Traffic Session feature in eu-west-1 to list the Traffic Target created in the eu-central-1. (I've also tried creating a Traffic Target in eu-west-1 for the load balancer located eu-central-1, but that also doesn't seem to be an option.)

Has anyone succeeded in setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

Document says  `The traffic mirror source and the traffic mirror target (monitoring appliance) can be in the same VPC. Or they can be in a different VPC connected via intra-Region VPC peering or a transit gateway.`.

Did you create a VPC peering between source VPC in 1 region with destination VPC in another region?